# Cannot call value of non-function type 'ThreadConfined.Type' - Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, realm, swift4

I upgraded a project I am working on to Swift 4.0.  After doing so I realized this was not the best idea.  I've fixed all bugs but one and can't figure it out.  I have installed RealmSwift in my project and am getting the following error in one of the Realm files.

ERROR: Cannot call value of non-function type 'ThreadConfined.Type'

```
 public init(to threadConfined: Confined) {
    let bridged = (threadConfined as! AssistedObjectiveCBridgeable).bridged
    swiftMetadata = bridged.metadata
    type = type(of: threadConfined).  ****ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE****
    objectiveCReference = RLMThreadSafeReference(threadConfined: bridged.objectiveCValue as! RLMThreadConfined)
}
```

Lesson learned about upgrading too soon.  I was hoping someone could give me a hand so I can start developing again.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm's master branch now contains support for Swift 4 and beta 1 of Xcode 9 ([#5006](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/5006)). Using a build of Realm Swift from source should get you up and running.

Comment: The link here takes you to the file needed.  https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/RealmSwift/ThreadSafeReference.swift

Comment: Are you able to point me to a source that explains how to create a build of Realm Swift from source?

Comment: The [GitHub repository's README](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa#building-realm) talks about building Realm from source. Alternatively, you can build from source by integrating Realm using CocoaPods or Carthage, and specifying a Git branch rather than a release version to build against.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that even though I was building from source (using CocoaPods), this issue was happening for me as well.

To solve it, two lines need to be removed (as seen in the file in @jonthornham's comment):

```
private let type: ThreadConfined.Type
```

and:

```
type = type(of:threadConfined)
```